# How do I remove crashplan from my Mac

Tags: terminal, macos, finder, applications

I recently tried out CrashPlan on my Macbook, but I decided not to go through with that.  However, now that I'm not going to be using CrashPlan after all, I can't figure out how to remove their app from my Mac.

I've tried simply opening up Finder and moving it to Trash but I get the following error when I try that:

[image: an error stating that the operation cannot be performed because I lack the permission to access the item in question]

I've also tried deleting it from the command-line using `rm -rf CrashPlan.app`; even when I run this as root, I still get:

```
rm: CrashPlan.app/Contents: Operation not permitted
rm: CrashPlan.app: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried doing this with the GNU version of `rm`, but I still get an error:

```
grm: cannot remove ‘CrashPlan.app/Contents’: Operation not permitted
```

I ran, `get info` on the CrashPlan app in Finder, and I noticed this:

[image: shows that the crashplan app is locked]

However, when I uncheck the `locked` field and then try to move it to Trash, I still get the same error that I got the first time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the Standard Uninstall procedure listed here: https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Getting_Started/Uninstalling_The_CrashPlan_App

Comment: @Deesbek yes, I ran all the `rm` commands above as root; I'm pretty sure that I even said that I had run them as root.

Comment: @AlexejMagura First, you need to disable SIP in recovery mode since the Library directory is protected by default now by macOS.  Additionally, the ".app" extension is a wrapper for a directory, and thus the `-r` flag is needed, and then optionally add the `-f` flag for force, e.g., `rm -rf /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/CrashPlan.app` and then it would work.  Running the uninstaller is unnecessary, and will likely result in old files and directories being left behind.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since Crashplan runs with elevated / non-standard permissions for an ordinary app, you will want to:

1. Reinstall the same or newer version of the software to correct whatever changes non-standard or half-removed. (Free download from http://www.code42.com/store/)
2. Run the uninstaller that is inside the package contents of the app. (Documented https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Getting_Started/Uninstalling_The_CrashPlan_App)
3. Optionally delete these two folders if they exist:

   - ~/Library/Application Support/CrashPlan
   - /Library/Application Support/CrashPlan

Answer (score 26):

I had this same exact problem and no amount of "uninstalling" would get this pesky application file to DELETE.  I even connected this Mac in Thunderbolt Target Mode to another Mac and tried to delete it that way.  No go.  I was at my wit's end, almost ready for a complete system backup, wipe and re-install.

Fortunately before getting that far, I was able to fix it by removing the "system immutable flag" via Terminal.app, using the "chflags noschg" command.

In the terminal:

```
cd ~/.Trash/
chflags -R noschg *
rm -fR * # or empty via Finder
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to run it as a sudo command: `sudo chflags -R noschg *`

Comment: I used a similar solution - because the uninstall didn't work... 
`sudo chflags noschg /Applications/CrashPlan.app` - then used appcleaner.

Answer (score 7):

Um.  I just went to the folder Library/Applicationsupport/CrashPlan and clicked on the uninstaller icon.  It uninstalled and it is gone now.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

CrashPlan app contains an uninstaller built in. You can access the Uninstaller app by following the steps below :

1. Go to Applications
2. Control Click on CrashPlan App & choose Show Package Contents
3. Go to Contents Folder
4. Locate Uninstall app & double click to run it
5. Authenticate using Administrator password & wait for it to complete

This whole process should be over it a minute or two.

Comment: Simple and effective. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

A much easier solution is to simply run the included uninstaller on the disk image.

Comment: Downloading a 50 Mb file is last thing people want to do to get rid of something. The uninstaller is included in the .app > Show Package Contents.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Fastest solution and worked on both computers was:

(a) Go to http://www.code42.com/store/
(b) Download free version of CrashPlan
(c) After clicking to install the pop-up with the application symbol (that you drop into your Applications folder) also has a small trashcan in the bottom right corner.
(d) After installation complete click the uninstall trashcan.
(e) All old and new crashplan files get removed instantly.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the Finder.
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>
3. A dialog box appears: Go to the folder.
4. Paste this text into the dialog box:
   Installed for everyone: `/Library/Application Support/CrashPlan/Uninstall.app`
   Installed per user: `~/Library/Application Support/CrashPlan/Uninstall.app`
5. Click Go.
6. Double-click Uninstall.
7. Follow the prompts to complete the uninstall process.
8. Remove the following directory from your system:
   Installed for everyone: `/Library/Application Support/CrashPlan`
   Installed per user: `~/Library/Application Support/CrashPlan`​

Answer (score 3):

I used this and it worked for me:

```
cd /Applications/CrashPlan.app/Contents/.Uninstall.app/Contents/Resources
sudo chmod u+x uninstall.sh
sudo ./uninstall.sh
```

Comment: Thank you!  On my version the directory was `/Applications/CrashPlan.app/Contents/Helpers/Uninstall.app/Contents/Resources`  -- worked!

Answer (score 1):

There are other reasons for wanting to delete a specific CrashPlan.app

I am in this camp. I have a backup copy of CrashPlan.app this is created by backup software and sometimes I need to delete the backup file and I get into the probem space of the question.

In this case, I am not deleting the primary CrashPlan.app and thus all the advice about uninstall does not apply.

Here is what I had to do:

```
# Change directory to the particular trashed or non-trash resident CrashPlan.app
cd /Volumes/Mavericks_NonSSD/_CCC SafetyNet/2015-08-05/Applications/CrashPlan.app/

sudo chflags -R noschg *
sudo rm -r Contents/
cd ..
sudo rm -fR CrashPlan.app/
ls -lsaG
```

All is good now for me....

I actually had to remove the CrashPlan.app from the trashcan and put it back where I deleted it from to get this to work, but it should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX the root user is disabled for security reasons. `sudo` might work, but if not, you can try the following. You need to login as administrator user. On my system, the default user (rxt) is not admin. So I need to do `su adminuser`, after which the adminuser password is needed. This makes you administrator, but not root. Now you can become root by using `sudo -i`. In some situations this is different from using `sudo` plus `rm` or some other command. If you need more rights, become root by using `sudo -i`!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't trash Crashplan, either. And when I did option/click, revealing the Package Contents, the uninstaller wouldn't work.

What worked for me was redownloading & reinstalling Crashplan. Then I did the option/click thing, ran the new uninstaller, and this seems to have completely removed Crashplan, including the pre-existing app that I couldn't get to move to the Trash.

Comment: I followed what harmon said above to redownload, but the install screen now comes with an uninstall option by double clicking a trash can instead of reinstalling the application.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't remove Crashplan also, tried delete, show contents and run uninstaller no success. Downloaded the app again and you get a new uninstall option. This worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal copy

```
sudo rm -R /Applications/CrashPlan.app
```

enter password, done.

You will still see the app icon but all process are stopped for good; for what I can see.